# context.SaveChanges() returns 0;

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to save new instance of JobLog to DB. Even thou I added a new instance of jobLog, context.SaveChanges() always returns 0. As you can seem I tried to console it and it always returns 0.

```
private readonly EntityContext context;
private TBCPaymentOptions _tbcPaymentOptions = null;

public AccountBilling(EntityContext _context) {
 context = _context;
}

public AccountBilling(EntityContext _context, IOptions < TBCPaymentOptions > tbcPaymentOptions) {
 context = _context;
 this._tbcPaymentOptions = tbcPaymentOptions.Value;

}

public void Save() {
 try {
  context.SaveChanges();

 } catch (Exception e) {
  Console.WriteLine(e);
  throw;
 }

}

public void CalculateUserCharge(DateTime date) {
 var latestJob = context.JobLogs.OrderByDescending(c => c.StartDate).Where(c => c.JobId == (int) JobEnum.CloseDay).FirstOrDefault();
 var jobLog = new JobLog();

 if (latestJob != null && latestJob.JobStatusID == (int) JobStatusEnum.Active) {
  jobLog.JobStatus.Id = (int) JobStatusEnum.Canceled;
  jobLog.EndDate = DateTime.Now;
  //this.Save();
  context.SaveChanges();
  if (context.SaveChanges() > 0) {
   Console.WriteLine("ok");
  } else {
   System.Console.WriteLine("NOPE");
  }
 } else {

  try {

   jobLog.JobId = (int) JobEnum.CloseDay;
   jobLog.JobStatusID = (int) JobStatusEnum.Active;
   jobLog.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
   // this.Save();
   context.SaveChanges();
   if (context.SaveChanges() > 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("ok2");
   } else {
    System.Console.WriteLine("2NOPE");
   }
   var result = new List < GetActiveUserPackagesForOpenBillingPeriodResult > ();

   using(var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(context.ConnectionString)) {
    conn.Open();

    using(var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("\"GetActiveUserPackagesForOpenBillingPeriod\"", conn)) {

     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("somedate", DateTime.Today);

     var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

     string x = DBNull.Value.Equals(reader) ? " " : reader.ToString();

     if (x != null) {
      while (reader.Read()) {
       result.Add(
        new GetActiveUserPackagesForOpenBillingPeriodResult {
         Amount = (decimal) reader["Amount"],
          PackageID = (int) reader["PackageID"],
          UserID = (int) reader["UserID"],
          AccountID = (int) reader["AccountID"],
          UserPackageStartDate = (DateTime) reader["UserPackageStartDate"],
        }
       );
      }
     }
     conn.Close();
    }

    var groupByResults = result.GroupBy(c => c.AccountID).Select(a => new {
     accountId = a.Key,
      lines = a.ToList()
    });

    foreach(var group in groupByResults) {

     var transactionHeader = new TransactionHeader() {

      TransactionHeaderTypeID = (int) TransactionHeaderTypeEnum.Charge,
       Date = date,
       CorrectionDescription = null,
       AccountID = group.accountId
     };

     foreach(var lineItem in group.lines) {
      transactionHeader.TransactionLines.Add(new TransactionLine() {
       UserID = lineItem.UserID,
        PackageID = lineItem.PackageID,
        Amount = this.CalculateUserChargeMethod(date, lineItem.Amount, lineItem.UserPackageStartDate)
      });

     }

     transactionHeader.TotalAmount = transactionHeader.TransactionLines.Sum(c => c.Amount);

     this.context.TransactionHeaders.Add(transactionHeader);

     //this.Save ();
     context.SaveChanges();
     if (context.SaveChanges() > 0) {
      Console.WriteLine("3OK");
     } else {
      System.Console.WriteLine("3NOPE");
     }

    }
    jobLog.EndDate = DateTime.Now;
    jobLog.JobStatusID = (int) JobStatusEnum.Inactive;
    //this.Save();
    context.SaveChanges();

    ClosePeriodOnEndOfMonth(date, conn);
   }

  } catch (Exception ex) {
   jobLog.EndDate = DateTime.Now;
   jobLog.JobStatusID = (int) JobStatusEnum.Canceled;
   //this.Save();
   context.SaveChanges();
   if (context.SaveChanges() > 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("OK4");
   } else {
    System.Console.WriteLine("NOPE4");
   }

   //throw ex;
  }
 }
}
```

EntityContext context should be working fine. That is exactly how I initialized it in the rest of the files. private readonly EntityContext context; and than putting it in constructor.

Comment: Sorry, but if you expect us to help, you're going to have to trim this code to a [mre]. This is far too long.

Comment: You are calling savechanges multiple times: `context.SaveChanges ();
                if (context.SaveChanges () > 0) {`. Of course the second will return 0, cause the first one did already do the changes and there no changes between first and second one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new `JobLog` instance, but you never add it to your context, i.e. `_context.Add(jobLog)`. As such, when you call `_context.SaveChanges()`, EF sees nothing to do, and just gives up. (The return value is the number of operations performed, which is obviously zero, because there was nothing to do.)